# arcpy.da.UpdateCursor() on field values in rows that meet "where_clause"

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, cursor

I'm looking to copy the values from the "Layer" field to the "COMMENTS" field... then change the string value in the "Layer" field to "Fiber Cable". The feature class is inside of a feature dataset within a GDB, not currently in the active map frame.

*only for features that meet this query* **"Entity = 'LWPolyline' And Layer LIKE '%Count%'"**

I've got the beginnings of an UpdateCursor loop, but it doesn't seem to change the field values. Weird thing is, I don't get an error when I run it but the changes don't get applied. What's going wrong?

```py
# Move "Layer" field values to "COMMENT" field and change "Layer" value to == "Fiber Cable"... for rows that meet the where_clause variable!
polyline_fc = "Polyline"
layer_field = "Layer"
comments_field = "COMMENTS"
where_clause = "Entity = 'LWPolyline' And Layer LIKE '%Count%'"



with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(polyline_fc, [layer_field, comments_field], where_clause) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        # Check if the feature meets the criteria
        comment_value = row[0]
        layer_value = row[1]
        if comment_value == 'LWPolyline' and 'Count' in layer_value:
            # Copy the value of the "Layer" field to the "COMMENTS" field
            row[1] = row[0]
            # Set the value for the "Layer" field
            row[0] = "Fiber Cable"
            cursor.updateRow(row)


print('"Layer" and "COMMENT" field values updated...')
```

Comment: Try adding some diagnostic `print` statements. How many rows are selected? Your `if` block is always evaluated if the WHERE works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your fields are `[layer_field, comments_field]` but you have the values reversed `comment_value = row[0]` and `layer_value = row[1]`. It should be `layer_value = row[0]` and `comment_value = row[1]`

But as Vince notes, the `where_clause` means that your `if` statement is redundant, so just use something like:

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(polyline_fc, [layer_field, comments_field], where_clause) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        # Copy the value of the "Layer" field to the "COMMENTS" field
        # Set the value for the "Layer" field to "Fiber Cable"
        cursor.updateRow(["Fiber Cable", row[0]])
```

Comment: Code sample you provided worked like a charm, thank you!